# Error in compilation servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, compiler-errors

I wrote a simple servlet:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestingServlet extends HttpServer {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<H1>Hello world</H1>");
    }
}
```

I tried to compile it and got:

> TestingServlet.java:6: error: cannot find symbol public class
>   TestingServlet extends HttpServer {
>                                       ^   symbol: class HttpServer 1 error

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`.

```
public class TestingServlet extends HttpServlet {
```

There is no `HttpServer` class in any of the packages you've imported.

Comment: Doesn't 'import javax.servlet.http.*;' import avax.servlet.http.HttpServlet?

Comment: @danpetruk Look carefully, `HttpServer` vs `HttpServlet`.